# AJAX not properly handling input

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm creating a WYSIWYG editor that saves the page via AJAX.

How it works is you add your elements (text, images, etc) to a DIV via the editor, and when you click "save", it sends that DIV's HTML through AJAX to a script that takes this HTML and writes it into "index.html", so it'll update the front page.

My problem: if the DIV has a background image, the AJAX page screws up.  Something to do with all the quotes is my guess (`<div style="background-url('picture.png');">`).  It handles everything else fine (images, text with both single and double quotes, etc).

I was looking through Firebug, and it's reporting that it's changing the `'picture.png'` to `&quot;picture.png&quot;`.  I've tried replacing the `&quot;` before it sends, but it's still breaking on the other end from all the quotes.

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What language is handling your AJAX on the other end?  If it's PHP, check out htmlentities(). Also, the ampersand (&) has broken my ajax requests in the past.

Comment: It is PHP.  If I check the output from Firebug it tells me it sent with the &quot;s around it.  If I check the input at the other end (the PHP AJAX receiving side), it gives me broken code in the $_POST array.

Comment: Did you try escaping the quotes with backslashes?  \' Or, hard-code the entity...here's something that might help: http://htmlhelp.com/tools/validator/problems.html

Comment: I don't know why that never occurred to me.  It was definitely the ampersands in &quot; screwing it up.  I tried it earlier, but I accidentally forgot to replace all of them instead of just the first one.  Silly me! :)  Thank you, Steve.  For anyone else with a similar problem, run the JS function replace(/&quot;/g,"\'") to your string to replace all the "&quot;"s with "\'"s.

Answer (score 0):

try dumping it server side - i'd expect its something to do with URL encoded (i.e. % encoded) quotes and/or your server side software adding backslashes